# Where is my validation function not going well for select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

3 years into js and i cant use simple validator libraries. So i decided to create my own. it works by adding the attribute **jmust** to all inputs,select,textarea etc. (not tried on radio yet.). the function checks if an input is empty and returns true.  the function code is as below

it works by calling the function with the form being its function input 
Problem is, it does not work on my select input. 

here is my sample code

```js
function jempty_form(x) {
  var n = false;
  $(x).find("[jmust]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      $(this).css("border", "none").css("border", "1px solid grey");
    } else {
      $(this).css("border", "1px solid red").addClass("animated shake");
      n = true;
      // alert("An input is Empty")
    }
  })
  return n;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class=" form-control " id="gender" jmust name="gender">
  <option disabled selected>Select Gender</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
</select>
<script>
  jempty_form("#myformid");
</script>
```

thanks..!

Comment: You should consider using `data-*` attributes instead of custom (invalid) attributes

Comment: please explain more

Comment: `jmust` is not a valid attribute for html tags. If you need custom attributes you should prefix them with `data-`: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: in your example the value of select is `disable` so it will be `false` always

Comment: u can just add a common class for all input and select in your form instead of using custom attribute or   $(x).find("input,select").each(function(){

Comment: you are right @SteveT. My first mistake is there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$(this).val() != ""` condition does not work for empty selects, because an empty string is not equal to `null` in JS.

You could simply check whether the value is [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) instead. This is done by simply testing `$(this).val()` which will be converted to a boolean when evaluating it in the context of a condition.

I would also recommend:

- using `data-` attributes (`data-jmust` here) instead of invalid attributes,
- using a CSS class for the error state instead of setting CSS manually (this way, you can easily restore the input to its initial state, and don't mix up styling with functionality).

**Demo:**

```js
function jempty_form(x) {
  var valid = true;
  
  $(x).find('[data-jmust]').each(function () {
    var action = $(this).val() ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass';
    valid = valid && !!$(this).val();
    $(this)[action]('invalid animated shake');
  });
  
  // For debugging purposes
  console.log(valid ? 'valid form' : 'invalid form');
  
  return valid;
}

jempty_form('#myformid');

$(function () {
  $(':input').on('change', function (e) {
    jempty_form('#myformid');
  });
});
```

```css
.invalid { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myformid">
  <select data-jmust class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender">
    <option disabled selected>Select Gender</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Just a little explanation on the `valid = valid && !!$(this).val();` line, it's a quick way of saying: "the form is valid if it's already valid (before the current field) and the value of the current input is also not empty".

Using `!!` converts the value into a boolean indicating whether it's *truthy* or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="myformid" action="" method="POST"> 
    <select class=" form-control " id="gender"  jmust name="gender">
        <option  disabled selected>Select Gender</option>
        <option value="female" >Female</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
    </select>

</form> 
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

    function jempty_form(x) {
        var n = false;
        $(x).find("[jmust]").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $(this).css("border", "none").css("border", "1px solid grey");
            } else {
                $(this).css("border", "1px solid red").addClass("animated shake");
                n = true;
                // alert("An input is Empty")
            }
        })
        return n;
    }

    console.log(jempty_form("#myformid"));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I made a minor change,

```
if ($(this).val()) {
```

in place of

```
if($(this).val() != ""){
```

Comment: if($(this).val()) and  if($(this).val() != "")  both works the same in his case

Comment: nope test it again, both show different results, the border color changes

Comment: though it is not advised to use a custom attr like 'jmust'

Comment: Right better have a data attribute or something